# Single loop gives one post duplicate

Tags: php, wordpress

I have Wordpress website that displays only one loop on the homepage.

Today I noticed that the loop returns a duplicate of a particular post.

I checked the database and there is only ONE physical presence of a post in a database.

this is how I define the loop parameters:

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 65,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type'=>'post'
    );
    query_posts($args);
```

If I put ID instead of "date" in the orderby clause, the problem does not exist.
But I need it to be ordered by date.

Any ideas why this is happening? I know this happens usually when we have two or more loops.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, that was just the call of the loop. The loop is pretty basic:
if ($allposts->have_posts()) : while ($allposts->have_posts()) : $allposts->the_post(); 
the_title();
endwhile;endif;

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
<?php
wp_reset_query();
?>
<?php
if ($allposts->have_posts()):
    while ($allposts->have_posts()):
        $allposts->the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Tried it already, and all the variations of it, nothing works :(